# Translate conditional function into R

Tags: r, statistics

I have function which denotes the probability density function:

[image]

S,mu,sigma are constant variables, where t goes from 0 to 1 i.e. `seq(0,1,0.01)`,
so that `f(T<t)` for `T=1`

How to translate this function - conditionality into R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it goes like this:

```
fun = function(t, S, sigma, mu){

  (S/sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2*t^3))*exp(-(S + mu*t)^2/(2*sigma^2*t))
}
```

Comment: hm. This is what I have got too. The results what I'm however getting are not identical with my example sheet. So mistake must be somewhere else. Thanks.

Comment: What input/ output your example expects?

Comment: Had some mistake in the code earlier. Now works as intended. I'm accepting your answer even the solution is so trivial! :)